# Is the Clanger's tandem rocket used in any episode?

Tags: tv, object-identification, clangers

During the title sequence of *[nu-Clangers](https://series.nu/serie/the-clangers)* (the third season released in 2015), two Clangers ride a tandem rocket past the Hoot planet. But I don't remember it appearing in any of the stories; does anyone know if it does?

[image: Clangers on a tandem]

Comment: Just to be clear, by "nu-Clangers", do you mean the 2015 Season 3?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, the version my daughter watches rather than one I watched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in episode 46 'The Golden Planet' released 15 June 2016:

[image: Clangers standing by the rocket ship]

[Episode on iPlayer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/b07gvkmr/clangers-46-the-golden-planet)